# How to classify new attribute in Weka?

Tags: weka, bayesian

I am using the weather.nominal dataset and NaiveBayes classifier in Weka.

I have been able to build the classifier, but now I would like to classify new records.  How can I use Weka to do that?

Can someone please tell me the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have trained your model, you can then supply a testing set for evaluation.

To do this, click on the 'Set...' Button next to the Supplied Test Set Radio Button as shown below:

[image: Selecting Testing Set]

Once a Testing Set is entered, you could Right click on the model and select 'Re-evaluate model on current test set' as shown below:

[image: Re-evaluation of testing data]

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please label this as answered if there are no other issues.